# Width of a flexbox column grows when I sort it, only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have an array corresponding to items that are displayed in a flex container. The html looks like this:

```
<div class="body">
  <section id="s1" class="package">1</section>
  <section id="s2" class="package">2</section>
  ...
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I collect an array, `sectionids` containing the `id`s of all `<section>` elements, and sort this array.  To re-display the sections in sorted order I do an insertion sort on the dom nodes so they end up in array order:

```
  function redisplay() {
    for (var i=1; i < sectionids.length; i++) {
      $(sectionids[i]).insertAfter($(sectionids[i-1]));
    }
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67urtLa8/7/)

Full snippet:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}

$(function() {
    var sections = $('section');
    var sectionids = [];
    sections.each(function(n, item) {
        $(item).prop('id', 's' + n);
        sectionids.push('#s' + n);
    });

    function redisplay() {
        for (var i = 1; i < sectionids.length; i++) {
            $(sectionids[i]).insertAfter($(sectionids[i - 1]));
        }
    }
    $('#shuffle').click(function() {
        shuffle(sectionids);
        // console.log("SECTIONS:", sectionids);
        redisplay();
    });
});
```

```css
.body {
    height: 500px;
}

.package {
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(46, 100, 41);
    color: white;
}

.body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=shuffle>shuffle</button>
<div class="body">
    <section class="package">1</section>
    <section class="package">2</section>
    <section class="package">3</section>
    <section class="package">4</section>
    <section class="package">5</section>
    <section class="package">6</section>
    <section class="package">7</section>
    <section class="package">8</section>
    <section class="package">9</section>
    <section class="package">10</section>
    <section class="package">11</section>
    <section class="package">12</section>
    <section class="package">13</section>
    <section class="package">14</section>
    <section class="package">15</section>
    <section class="package">16</section>
    <section class="package">17</section>
    <section class="package">18</section>
    <section class="package">19</section>
    <section class="package">20</section>
    <section class="package">21</section>
    <section class="package">22</section>
    <section class="package">23</section>
    <section class="package">24</section>
    <section class="package">25</section>
    <section class="package">26</section>
    <section class="package">27</section>
    <section class="package">28</section>
    <section class="package">29</section>
</div>
```

This works great on IE, Edge, and FF, but on Chrome the width of the first column grows every time you sort. The size pops back to where it is supposed to be if I resize the browser, but not if I issue a `window.resizeBy/To`.

Is there any way to work around this that doesn't involve setting a fixed width and using `align-items: flex-start` (the columns become very disjoint if I do that)?

**Update:** I've found a horrible hack that works (calling the function below after `redisplay()`), but it seems rather fragile (e.g. extracting `$b.width()` into a variable doesn't work):

```
  function fix_chrome() {
    var $b = $('.body');
    $b.width($b.width() + 1);
    $b.width($b.width() - 1);
  }
```

Comment: the use of column-css seems to bring no bugs, not sure it meets your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/67urtLa8/12/  prefixed : https://jsfiddle.net/67urtLa8/14/

Comment: @GCyrillus unfortunately it does not, I need the number of columns to change dynamically with the content (ie. more columns if more sections and vice-versa). Previously I've also had problems with boxes being cut between columns in some browsers, but perhaps that is no longer an issue (I wasn't able to provoke it now..)?

Comment: adding width: 33%; explicit to the package style seems to correct this behaviour, but as you said you don't want to add width it may not be a solution for you...

Comment: perhaps fill an issue on [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)

Comment: @michaPau no, not a solution unfortunately.  If your remove 5 of the sections the flex layout beautifully fills the entire width with two columns.  I don't know a priori how many sections there will be.

Comment: @thebjorn , when boxes are displayed inline-block they do not break into different columns (it's been a fixed for while till the dedicated  css rule works :)